# Java Threading best practise for Sessions

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server, scalability

Hello @all on StackOverflow,
i am currently developing a Server Client application which communicates over HTTPS and does some Task which have to run in a seperate thread on the Server aswell as on the Client.

I am not really concert about thread efficiency on the Client side.

The normal Server Task Looks like this:

1. HTTPS Server recieves Login equest.
2. Opens up one longpolling thread for communication.
3. Server recieves instructions to open
4. Server opens a Client socket and a thread to read from it.
5. Server recieves message to Close socket.
6. Clientsocket thread should wait now.

-Besides: The longpolling thread should wait() as long as it has not recieved any data from the socketthread.

So in most cases one user can ahve multiple sockets on the serverside so one session consists of:

LongpollingThread<1---1>USER<1---0..5>Socket

My question now is what is the best practise to get some decend scalability?
Is it better to write permanent Thread which has a while loop inside.
Or is it better to write Tasks which run on a Threadpool and die after one I/O cycle.

Can´t find a good answer online.
Maybe it is to specific..

Thanks in advance 
Bladerox

Comment: You can't do what you describe over HTTPS. It isn't a server-side polling protocol. And TCP servers don't open client sockets. I suggest you do some more research.

Comment: I think my concept is unclear.
The Client sends https requests to the Server which holds them until it has data for the Client. It the sed the reepsonse. Which allows a bi-directional communication.
The Server openes Client sockets to a diffrent Server.
All in all it will be a Tunneling application....

Comment: So fix your question to agree.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use some kind of servlet engine or application server. Lots of your problems will be solved in there. Eg using async servlet processing will help you in your server component.

At client site: did you have a look at the multicast things in java.nio?